# SequenceContainer base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, containers

In Java all containers are in a hierarchy of abstract base classes:

```
List<String> v1 = new LinkedList<String>();
AbstractSequentialList<String> v2 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Is there an analogue for [SequenceContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer) and `std::vector` in C++?

Comment: A word of warning -- don't try to write C++ code using Java as a model, and vice-versa.  All that will happen is C++ code that looks weird, has bugs, leaks memory all over the place, is inefficient, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `std::vector` has no (standard, documented) base class, nor does it have any `virtual` methods.  The C++ standard library doesn't use runtime polymorphism much aside from the iostream classes.

The C++ standard library is geared more towards static, compile-time polymorphism with templates.  *SequenceContainer* is just a name for the way some set of classes can be interacted with.  The intent is that you can write template code that interacts with objects only by that documented interface and it will work with any class that fulfills those requirements.